# How to make the left edge of a background-image position at the horizontal halfway point

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The setup of my problem is simple: I want a background image on an element to be positioned with its left edge halfway between left and right side of its container. So like

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-on-right" id="this-dude">
    <div class="text-holder">
        <p>His arms spaghetti, knees weak, palms spaghetti. There's spaghetti on his sweater already, mom's spaghetti. He's nervous, but on the surface he looks calm spaghetti.        
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-on-right { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position-x: 50%; background-size: contain; }
.image-on-right > .text-holder { width: 50%; }
#this-dude { background-image: url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/mEPV2I6dgRM/hqdefault.jpg); }
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/e78xbuna/)

except there the background image has its *center* at the 50% mark, not it's left side at the 50% mark. So if there existed a property I could apply like `background-position-translate: translateX(-50%);` that would be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of realizing this layout.

First, using a background image will not work (unless you specify a with for the image, which is probably too restrictive).

If I were doing it, I would use absolute positioning to place the image to the right of `.text-holder`.

You can do this by specifying `position: relative` to `.image-on-right`, the parent block, and then `position: absolute` to `.img-holder`, with offsets `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` to match the height of the text in `.text-holder`, and then `left: 50%` to get the left edge of the image where it is needed.
I applied `width: 50%`, but this is not strictly needed.

Finally, to get the image to scale to the height of the absolute positioned container, use `height: 100%`, and the width will adjust accordingly.

This may not look elegant, but it works.  Alternatively, you could place the image as a background image for the `.img-holder` element, but the net result is the same and you still the `.img-holder` element.

**Note:** I assumed that you did not want the text to overlap the image, otherwise, the background image technique would have worked (approximately).

```css
.image-on-right {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    position: relative;
}
.image-on-right > .text-holder {
    width: 50%;
}
.image-on-right .img-holder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-on-right">
    <div class="text-holder">
        <p>His arms spaghetti, knees weak, palms spaghetti. There's spaghetti on his sweater already, mom's spaghetti. He's nervous, but on the surface he looks calm spaghetti.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-holder"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/mEPV2I6dgRM/hqdefault.jpg"></div>
</div>
```